# Displaying data for an android/iphone app using JSON and Javascript querying mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, json

Alright, long story short, this is an app that my company is developing that has seen about 3 different coders fresh out of college working on it. Every time a new one would take over, it got worse.

My area is typically strictly PHP / C language, and you'd think given this backing of knowledge I'd be able to figure this out. But, no. I've gotten pretty close, but so far no luck.

Basically, the guy that was developing the app for Apple dropped out, so my co-worker ran the Android app through a "make this compatible with apple" type program, so that's what we're continuing to go with.

Boss gave me the go ahead to post the question here, we basically just need this thing done and out of our hair, and even though I'm usually pretty good with figuring out what's going on with a piece of code, this one just keeps on not working.

I have created a sub-folder on my company's server that links to text files that display the code that I need help with. This way the question doesn't get ungodly long with code blocks because I'm not even sure what part of the code is relevant anymore.

http://lmk-design.net/stackquestion/  (Fixed link)

It's run 100% through javascript HTML ID injection.

As you can see from the javascript file, it uses json to call php files on the server, which I included in .txt format at the above link.

So all I am trying to do, is get a readout of nice data displayed on the calendar page pulled from the same exact database that the other pages are pulling from.

I have tried everything and cannot get it to work. I've gotten it to print out a json array that looked terrible, but I cannot seem to make it parse the data and display it as nicely formatted html AT ALL.

I noticed in my console in firebug, my call back (get_calendar) has a JSON tab instead of an HTML tab like the rest of them, but I can't figure out why that is.

Anything that refers to 'calendar' or 'events' in the code are likely my attempts at making this work.

I understand the general premise of how this works. A PHP file on the server pulls data from the database and dumps it via a generic select statement. Javascript on the app pulls that PHP file and organizes the data that was dumped. It seems simple enough, but no matter WHAT I do, nothing works.

So any and all help or pushes in the right direction for getting this to work would be an absolute GODSEND.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). My browser is blocking the link you provided with a "High Rick Website Blocked" message citing `Mal/HTMLGen-A`.

Comment: I uploaded the folder to my personal hosting account and changed the link above, I hope that takes care of the issue. If not, it's the stupid app code itself, which makes everything a lot harder. I've created a new PHP file on the remote server that matches the ones used for the other pages, and I've created a javascript function that I've been fiddling with for the past week or so. The problem is that the code is so messy and I'm so unfamiliar with Javascript that it's like trying to solve a 1000pc jigsaw puzzle blindly.